# Find out if std::ostream& refers to a global object

Tags: c++, output, outputstream

If the following method

```
template<typename... Args>
void report(std::ostream&str, Args&&... args)
{
    (str << ... << args);
}
```

is called synchronously from different threads with the same `str`, the write from different threads may be mangled. Therefore, I use instead

```
template<typename... Args>
void report(std::ostream&str, Args&&... args)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    (ostr << ... << args);
    str << ostr.str();
}
```

Now, I wonder whether instead it would be possible to detect whether this is indeed necessary, i.e.

```
{
    if(is_global_object(str)) {      // how to implement this?
        std::ostringstream ostr;
        (ostr << ... << args);
        str << ostr.str();
    } else
        (str << ... << args);
}
```

Question: how to implement `is_global_object(str)`? I would be happy to detect all of `std::cout`, `std::wcout`, `std::clog`, `std::wclog`, `std::cerr`, `std::wcerr`.

Comment: I recommend that you actually measure the time spent in both funtions. If the difference is negligible (what I think it is), then just use the second version.

Comment: In short: You can't implement such a function. Reason being that C++ doesn't have any kind of [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection).

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: This is pointless. Being "global" **is not** equal to being "shared". And "shared" is your problem. Even if there was way to check for being global, there's definitely no way to check sharing. Thus you have to assume that the result can be mangled.

Comment: A non global object may be shared too. You don't want to synchronize non global objects?

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, my suggestion is that either you stop sharing the stream, or you implement locking/synchronization in the threads. Alternatively create a new overload of the `report` function which takes a [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) as argument and do the locking inside the function.

Comment: FYI, C++20 should have [`osyncstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream)

Comment: BTW your "solution" (the middle code) **is not thread safe**. There is no such guarantee in the standard for general `ostream` that single write is thread safe.

Comment: Just curious, why the parentheses around the stream insertions? My immediate reaction is that they are redundant; am I missing something?

Comment: @PeteBecker These are [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: @Walter — got it. I haven’t been paying attention to newer developments in the standard. Not to mention only glancing at the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, definitely not possible. What if one thread were to create a local `ostream` and then pass a reference to it to a different thread? Not global, but still shared. The global-ness of an object does not determine its locality.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all there is no way to check if some reference is a reference to a global object. At least not without some hard platform specific hacks (static memory scan?) which may not work. Dont go down that road.

Secondly (and more important) your problem is not "global". It is "shared". Why do you think that a variable has to be global to be shared? On the other hand there may be globals that are not shared. But anyway for that there is no solution as well. No hack will help you here.

Thirdly, your middle code is not thread safe as well. There is no guarantee that single write has to be thread safe. In some cases it is (std::cout), but there is no such guarantee for std::ostream. I can easily write my own stream with non thread-safe write.

Last but not least, you can avoid all of that by taking advantage of classes and mutexes. Something like this:

```
class Logger {
    public:
        Logger(std::ostream& stream): stream {stream}
        {};

        template<typename... Args>
        void log(Args&&... args)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg {mu};
            (stream << ... << args);
        }

    private:
        std::ostream& stream;
        std::mutex mu;
};
```

and don't worry about all thread safety nuanses at all.

For better scaling you may want to have a look at some lock-free queueing of messages.